# mySQL - Select 2 latest comments for each posts

Tags: mysql, join

I trying to limit for only 2 comments for each posts,
i select in the post table and i want to get 2 comments for each

### Schema:

**Posts table**

```
------------------------------------
  id   |   content   |    date     |
  25    |   hello     |  20/10/2013 |
```

**Comments TABLE**

```
------------------------------------------------
  id   |   content   |    post   |    date     |
  1    |   hello     |    25     |  20/10/2013 |
```

Could you help me friends, i'm so confused !
Thanks before, Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: You should give us a table model at least

Comment: post some code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query returns last 2 comments for each post:

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a415/1)

```
select p.content post_content,
       c.content comment_content

from posts p
left join comments c on 
    (p.id=c.post)
    and 
    c.id>
    (select id from comments  
        where post=p.id
        order by id DESC LIMIT 2,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`MySQL supports the LIMIT keyword, which allows you to control how many rows are returned; ideal when displaying data over many pages. You can use LIMIT in your sql query like this`

In your case

```
select * from posts p join comments c on p.id=c.post and
      c.id> (select id from comments  where post=p.id order by id DESC LIMIT 2,1)
```

Comment: Excuse me sir, i know your way are right, but i want to get 2 comments for each posts, so it will be need a JOIN clause, Where is it, i don't see it in your query ?

Comment: post the required schema !!

Answer (score 1):

Syntax may not be perfect, did not have time to create fiddle. But this has subquery which should get the latest 2 comments related to the post and join that to the post itself. Have to consider that fact that there may be no comments at all hence the test for Is Null from the Left Join.

```
Select *
From Posts p
Left Outer Join Comments c
On c.post = p.id
Where 
    (        c.id Is Null
        Or    c.id In
        (
            Select c2.id
            From Comments c2
            Where c2.post = p.id
            Order by c2.id Desc
            Limit 2
        )
    )
```